# Dataframe: изменение столбцов даты на другой формат

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Есть датафрейм с сстолбцом датам. Нудно перевести их из формата 2020-08-24 , 2019-09-10 в формат 2020,8,24, 2019,9,10 - тоесть без '0' и '-'
Заодним я еще отнимаю 1 месяц от них.

```
0   2020-08-24
1   2020-08-24
2   2020-08-24
... ...
12027   2019-09-10
12028   2019-09-10
12029   2019-09-09
```

Что пробую сделать: изменить тип столбца в 'to_datetime', отнять 30 дней и перевести обратно в str, чтобы заменить '-' на ','

```
df['Date_m'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_m']).dt.date
df['Date_new'] = df['Date_m'] - pd.offsets.Day(30) 
# ? здесь нужно какое то преобразование в str 
df['Date_new'] = df['Date_new'].str.replace('-',',')
```

Но даже здесь получаю ошибку `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!` 
К тому же как убрать из месяцев цифры '0' не знаю.
Как решить задачу? Может есть более красивое решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете перевести дату в строку нужного формата с помощью [`dt.strftime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html)

```
In [35]: df
Out[35]: 
     idx       date
0      0 2020-07-25
1      1 2020-07-25
2      2 2020-07-05
3  12027 2019-08-11
4  12028 2019-08-11
5  12029 2019-08-10

In [36]: df.dtypes 
Out[36]: 
idx              int64
date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object

In [37]: df.date.dt.strftime('%Y,%m,%d').str.replace(',0', ',')
Out[37]: 
0    2020,7,25
1    2020,7,25
2     2020,7,5
3    2019,8,11
4    2019,8,11
5    2019,8,10
Name: date, dtype: object
```

Comment: @Nikolay_Smirnov .dt есть только у дат. Наверное в этом столбце какие-то значения не являются датами. Вы применили к нему pd.to_datetime()?